# For JMeter tests, is it possible to send payload as a parameter for different runs

Tags: jmeter

Each run of test could have a different payload. This could be sent in Jenkins job too as a parameter. So if there are say 5 different payloads, one run has one payload file. Another run would have another payload file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible both on Jenkins and JMeter levels.

For example you have 5 files in a folder called `/some/folder` named like `file1`, `file2`, etc. and would like each build to use the next file

In Jenkins if you're using [pipelines](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) you could do something like:

```
def BUILD_NUMBER = env.BUILD_NUMBER.toInteger()
def payloadIndex = (BUILD_NUMBER - 1) % 5 
def payload = "${workspace}/some/folder/file${payloadIndex}"
```

once done you can pass this `payload` to JMeter via `-J` command-line argument and read it using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) where required

Alternatively if you are on a [freestyle job](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_setup_build_jobs.htm) you can do it on JMeter level using a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) code:

```
def BUILD_NUMBER = System.getenv('BUILD_NUMBER') as int 
def payloadIndex = (BUILD_NUMBER - 1) % 5

def filesList = new File('/some/folder').list().sort()

def payload = new File(filesList[payloadIndex]).getCanonicalPath()

vars.put('payload', payload)
```

Comment: TY! Could u share which JSR223 element to use? I see JSR223 Pre and Post processors.