# Further question to - For JMeter tests, how send payload as a parameter for different runs

Tags: jmeter

This is question after [For JMeter tests, is it possible to send payload as a parameter for different runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76000084/for-jmeter-tests-is-it-possible-to-send-payload-as-a-parameter-for-different-ru). Not able to tag Dmitri T.

I added a JSR223 Post Processor. In its script, I wrote `def BUILD_NUMBER = System.getenv('BUILD_NUMBER') as int def payloadIndex = (BUILD_NUMBER - 1) % 5 File folder = new File("C:\Users\path\to\TwoPayloads"); def filesList = new File(folder).list().sort() def payload = new File(filesList[payloadIndex]).getCanonicalPath() vars.put('payload', payload)` I deleted payload from Body of script. I put ${__P(payload)} in Body data of sampler. I run the job. I get 400. Please advice.

Comment: Yeah...i added in comments further question. Not getting response to them. Not able to tag person who answered Dmitri T. So thought of asking qn again with next steps.